# Ubuntu Nexus 7 - Daily Pre-Installed - Tegra 3 Driver

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-touch

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Nexus 7 tablet using the daily pre-installed image build. It works, but the screen is very very slow, and when I see the details, graphics says unknown. Is there a driver I can install for this?

Comment: I found this: https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra
So it looks like there is actually an official driver, but it's something for building a full development linux image based on ubuntu 12.04 and needs to be installed into the device, etc; not just the driver. Any advice on how install this driver on Ubuntu 13.04 ??
Thanks.

Comment: I did a test. Downloaded the driver pack file, copied the content of "rootfs/usr/lib" to my device "/usr/lib". It started copying but after 2 seconds Ubuntu crashed sending me back to the login screen. I restarted my Nexus. When back, first I noticed was that all the artifacts the keyboard had disappeared (It always shows some artifacts), keyboard and the screen was crystal clear and faster! Logged in and thats where it got wrong; I had no dock or menu bar, or anything, just the desktop. Right clicked the desktop went to backdrop change,the "window" looked perfect, but incomplete desktop.

Comment: So, I gave up. And installed Android back. It could be great to have an stable and fast Ubuntu version that can be installed to the Nexus devices, but the actual works badly bad; at least that was my case.
Thanks.